# Dynamic API - Associate ManyToMany Entities on Create

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

Is it possible to associate entities on an API Create call, where the relationship is ManyToManyRelationship as below?

```
{
  "SchemaName": "testscheduleid_testid",
  "Entity1LogicalName": "testschedule",
  "Entity2LogicalName": "test",
  "IntersectEntityName": "testschedule_test",
  "Entity1IntersectAttribute": "testscheduleid",
  "Entity2IntersectAttribute": "testid",
}
```

The example on [Create an entity using the Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg328090(v=crm.8)#associate-entities-on-create) only show OneToMany.

Or /tests(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002)/testschedules/$ref is the only way through REST API

Comment: I created a github issue - lets see: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerapps-docs/issues/2432

Answer (score 0):

Web API has only the concept of two types of relationships:

- Single-value
- Collection value

When it comes to N:N relationships, they are just collection-valued relationships on both sides. While there is an intersect entity between them, you just ignore it when it comes to working with the relationships.

If you look at the current documentation, you will see an example here [Associate table rows on create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/create-entity-web-api#associate-table-rows-on-create)

Using this code:

```
    POST [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts?$select=name&$expand=primarycontactid($select=fullname),Account_Tasks($select=subject) HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
    OData-Version: 4.0
    Accept: application/json
    Prefer: return=representation
    
    {
        "name": "Sample Account",
        "primarycontactid@odata.bind": "/contacts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)",
        "Account_Tasks@odata.bind": [
            "/tasks(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002)",
            "/tasks(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003)"
       

 ]
}
```

While this is a one-to-many relationship, using the correct collection-valued navigation property that represents an N:N relationship, it should work the same way.

Ignore the intersect entity.
Look for the correct collection-valued navigation property in the $metadata